# Coverage XML output file is not seen in Github Actions uses

Tags: github, github-actions, code-coverage, cobertura

Im trying to use the coverage report by irongut, for a test method, where in a docker container the test is running, but the output XML file is not seen. What am I missing, the path is different? Or am i completely messing up the flow.

Github Actions input part:

```
    uses: addnab/docker-run-action@v3
    with:
      image: pythontest:latest
      options: |
        -e MYSQL_DATABASE=lena-db
      run: |
        coverage run --rcfile=.coveragerc manage.py test lena_transport
        coverage xml -o ./coverage
  -
    name: Coverage report
    uses: irongut/CodeCoverageSummary@v1.3.0
    with:
      filename: ./coverage/*.xml
      badge: true
      fail_below_min: true
      format: markdown
      hide_branch_rate: false
      hide_complexity: true
      indicators: true
      output: both
      thresholds: '60 80'
```

Output:

```
Run irongut/CodeCoverageSummary@v1.3.0
/usr/bin/docker run --name ghcrioirongutcodecoveragesummaryv130_2ecc5b --label 229416 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "version" -e "INPUT_FILENAME" -e "INPUT_BADGE" -e "INPUT_FAIL_BELOW_MIN" -e "INPUT_FORMAT" -e "INPUT_HIDE_BRANCH_RATE" -e "INPUT_HIDE_COMPLEXITY" -e "INPUT_INDICATORS" -e "INPUT_OUTPUT" -e "INPUT_THRESHOLDS" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/ltlwrk-python/ltlwrk-python":"/github/workspace" ghcr.io/irongut/codecoveragesummary:v1.3.0  "--files" "coverage/**/coverage.cobertura.xml" "--badge" "true" "--fail" "true" "--format" "markdown" "--hidebranch" "false" "--hidecomplexity" "true" "--indicators" "true" "--output" "both" "--thresholds" "60 80"
Error: No files found matching glob pattern.
```

EDIT:
I used PWD and LS -A to print out the working directory and to check if the file is present, its right there, the paths are correct to my understanding still unable to generate the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution was to create a bind mount from the container to the host, so the coverage reporter can access.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking to write the XML to a file called `./coverage`, but are then looking for `./coverage/*.xml`.  You mentioned using `ls -a`, can you show us what it is showing you?

Comment: The file is present as coverage.xml

Comment: OK, your "Coverage report" step is using `filename: ./coverage/*.xml`. That pattern won't find "coverage.xml".

Comment: I realized the problem. but still dont know how to fix it.
the coverage file is created in a docker environment which is for ex: dir/coverage.xml
but the reporter is looking at a different path which is:
/home/runner/work/<reponame>/<reponame>/coverage.xml

Comment: the two are in a different environement and dont know how to make them to find each other.